# Wordpress + bbPress + xampp results broken stylesheet links

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I'm trying to add bbPress to Wordpress, which is installed on my local XAMPP server. Everything is fine except the static file links. So the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/wp-content/C:UsersxunDropboxcodeswebsiteswordpresswp-contentpluginsbbpress/templates/default/css/bbpress.css?ver=2.5-5199
```

So wordpress put a absolute path(without back slashes) where there should be a relative path. What causes this and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue for Windows users in bbPress 2.5 and has been fixed, please update to bbPress 2.5.1

http://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/